# Javascript Enabled input type when checkbox checked and disable when checkbox unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

my javascript is here:

```
function enable(id) {
        var i = (document.getElementById('haha').checked);

        if(i= true) {
        document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled= false;
        document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled= false;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled= true;
        document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled= true;
        }
        }
```

when i checked checkbox, the textbox will enabled, but when i unchecked, that textbox still enable, i want to this textbox go disabled after i unchecked. how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`=` is *assignment* (setting the value of a variable), so `if (i = true)` *sets* `i` to `true` and then branches into the `if` block. To do a comparison, normally you'd use `==` or `===`, but with booleans, that's never necessary; just check the value directly:

```
if (i) {
    // Enable it
} else {
    // Disable it
}
```

In *this* case, though, you can just use `i` directly:

```
document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled = !i;
document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled = !i;
```

There's also no need for the `()` around your check of `checked`.

I'd probably do this:

```
function enable(id) {
    var disabled = !document.getElementById('haha').checked;
    document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled = disabled;
    document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled = disabled;
}
```

There, I'm getting the value of the checkbox and inverting it, then using that as the `disabled` flag on the other inputs. I'd do it like that because it's nice and easy to debug, I can see the `disabled` value easily in the debugger when I'm stepping through code.

Some folks really, really like to do things in one expression. (I think that's very overrated.) They might do this:

```
function enable(id) {
    document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled =
        document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled =
            !document.getElementById('haha').checked;
}
```

...since the result of an assignment is the value that was assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
function chkBox(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
    $(obj).parents("tr").find("input[type='number']").prop('disabled', !$(obj).is(":checked"));
    $(obj).parents("tr").find("input[type='hidden']").prop('disabled', !$(obj).is(":checked"));
}
```

call the function and pass this.

```
onclick="chkBox(this)"
```